# link with image

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink

i have list of links

- link1
- link2
- link3

how can i add an image left on each link with css style not html tags?

Comment: can you see page http://trading-it.ru/1.htm and say where is error?

Comment: put the `style` attribute on the last `li` in the `ul` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS to suppress the existing list bullets (`list-style:none`) then specify your own image using `background`, as in this snippet:

```
li {
 list-style: none;
 background: url(16-heart-red-xxs.png) no-repeat left center;
 ...
```

For more information, see: http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/aa012907.htm

**EDIT:**

See below for new source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    li
    {
        list-style: none;
        background: url(/images/servers.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: left;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://trading-it.ru/Category/1--.aspx">??????? ? ????????? ????????????</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://trading-it.ru/Category/2--.aspx">????? ??? ????????</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://trading-it.ru/Category/3--.aspx">??????????, ????????</a></li>

        <li><a href="http://trading-it.ru/Category/4--apple.aspx">????????? Apple</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://trading-it.ru/Category/10--.aspx">??????????? ???????????</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://trading-it.ru/Category/11--.aspx">???????????? ?????????????</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://trading-it.ru/Category/12--.aspx">????????? ? ??????? ???????</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://trading-it.ru/Category/13--.aspx">????????? ?????????</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://trading-it.ru/Category/14-.aspx">?????????</a></li>

        <li><a href="http://trading-it.ru/Category/15--.aspx">?????????? ? ??????</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://trading-it.ru/Category/16--.aspx">??????????????? ????????????</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://trading-it.ru/Category/17--.aspx">??????? ????????????</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://trading-it.ru/Category/21-111.aspx">111</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The style is only applied to the last `li` element, it needs to be applied to all that you want to have an image on. I suggest adding a `<style>...</style>` section to your document to simplify and centralize.

Comment: yes, but i do it for small test. in any case you sample not work, see the page http://trading-it.ru/1.htm

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you are really wanting to do is to change the • circular bullet point to an image that you have specified. Like so:

`<UL  id="navlist">`

```
#navlist
{
list-style: none;
}

#navlist li 
{
padding-left: 10px;
background-image: url(images/arrow.gif);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: no, i simply want to add an image left side on each link, no matter will be bullet or not. images can be different

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `list-style-image` property for that:

```
li {
    list-style-image: url("/images/servers.png");
}
```

This will add the image and not a circle, square etc. to each element of the list.